# React, github enterprise, getting blank page publishing on ghpages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, github-enterprise

I'm new to react! I have a github enterprise account, and I'm trying to publish on GH pages a demo of the app for my company. On local server it works but when I publish ( npm run build ) I always get a blank page. I have updated the home in the package.json to https://pages.github.kp.org/E546371/barcode and I'm sure this is 100% correct, because if you type the address in the browser and click on the source, you can see the correct index.html page source, but the react app just won't run. I also have tried to set the home to https://pages.github.kp.org/E546371/barcode/

If I make changes to the Meta of the index.html and redeploy I see the changes, so again the homepage looks correct, but the react app doesn't run. Any suggestion?

This is a part of my package.json, I also have tried to change private to false, but still nothing

```json
{
  "name": "barcode",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "home": "https://pages.github.kp.org/E546371/barcode",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

this is my index.js

I tried to change the homepage, but I think it's correct as I can see the source of index.hmtl, but the app doesn't get rendered.

Those are the error I'm getting in the console:

```
main.f2276a4e.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.34cc38e5.css:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
/favicon.ico/:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
pages.github.kp.org/:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
main.34cc38e5.css:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://hnfanknocfeofbddgcijnmhnfnkdnaad/content.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
pages.github.kp.org/:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://hnfanknocfeofbddgcijnmhnfnkdnaad/requestProvider.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

So from the error, I understand that it's trying to get the source from:

https://pages.github.kp.org/static/css/main.34cc38e5.css

While the correct URL should be:

https://pages.github.kp.org/E546371/barcode/static/css/main.34cc38e5.css

Strange things on my personal github, I get the correct path when I deploy, only on github enterprise the URLs get deployed wrong.

How can I fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: The property you want is `homepage`. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#step-1-add-homepage-to-packagejson

Comment: I already sent the homepage property as you can see in the package.json file I have posted.

Comment: Yours is using `home` which is not the same as `homepage`

Comment: oh..... you are so right! Thank you so much for catching that.